# Why floor of lg(n-1) is same with floor of lg(n)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I'm studying worst case of binary search algorithm and there was difficult thing to understand.

They proof that:

> W(n) = floor of (lg(n) + 1). (i'll say floor using '⌊ ⌋')

I'll write all proof when `n` is power of 2 is done.
I have the proof when `n` is not a power of 2.

- Induction Base

  - When n = 1, ⌊lg(n)⌋+1 = ⌊lg1⌋+1 = 0+1 = 1 = W(1)
- Induction Hypothesis

  - For some n>= 1 and 1 < k < n, suppose W(k) = ⌊lg(k)⌋+1
- Induction Step

  - if ⌊n/2⌋ = n/2
    W(n) = 1 + W(⌊n/2⌋)
    = 1 + ⌊lg⌊n/2⌋⌋ + 1
    = 2 + ⌊lg⌊n/2⌋⌋
    = 2 + ⌊lg(n/2)⌋
    = 2 + ⌊lg(n) - 1⌋
    = 2 + ⌊lg(n)⌋ -1
    = 1 + ⌊lg(n)⌋
- Induction Step (Cont'd)

  - if ⌊n/2⌋ = (n-1)/2
    W(n) = 1 + W (⌊n/2⌋)
    = 1 + ⌊lg⌊n/2⌋⌋ + 1
    = 2 + ⌊lg{(n-1)/2}⌋
    = 2 + ⌊lg(n-1) - 1⌋
    = 2 + ⌊lg(n-1)⌋ - 1
    = 1 + ⌊lg(n-1)⌋
    = 1 + ⌊lg(n)⌋

Here is my question: Why last two step is same?

I can't understand and in my book, there is no explain about it.
Please help me.

Comment: `lg` is the logarithm? it is usually `log` or `ln`

Comment: lg means log having base of 2

Comment: It is not true in general that floor(lg(n)) = floor(lg(n-1)). For example, when n is any power of 2.

Comment: it suppose n is not power of 2. then it can be right??? I edited suppose.

Comment: It might be that some information was omitted or that there is a typing error. It could be that they meant to write a "<=" or that they misused the equality sign in the meaning of Landau-notation. Would the proof work if you think in terms of complexity classes? Since you usually only need a constraint from above, not the correct theta class?

Comment: Yes, if n isn't a power of 2, then floor(lg(n)) = floor(lg(n-1)).

Comment: I changed my question. :)

Comment: i got it thanks all!!! especially Paul Hankin :)

Comment: Inductive hypothesis is not correctly stated... it should be for all ...